# Converted a object List to DateTime List but I just want the Date not the Time

Tags: c#, list, datetime

I have an object List called list and I converted it by:

```
List<DateTime> dateList = list.Select(date => Convert.ToDateTime(date[0])).ToList();
```

My object list contained values such as 09/04/2015 but when I do this list conversion I get values in the format of 09/04/2015 00:00:00.

I was just wondering how I can get it so just the date is stored in the dateList?

The .Date property does not work

Comment: you cant remove the Time from `DateTime`, but wherever you display it, you can show just the date using the `DateTime.Date` property and/or using some formatting

Comment: What does `date[0]` do? In other words, what does your list contain? Is it strings? That wouldn't build. Hmm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET doesn't really have a type that represents *just* a `Date`. However, if you know how you want your date to be displayed at this point in your code, then you can convert it into a string.

```
const string dateFormat = "d"; // e.g. "9/4/2015"
List<string> dateList = list
    .Select(date => Convert.ToDateTime(date[0]).ToString(dateFormat))
    .ToList();
```

You can change the `dateFormat` to use any of the standard strings listed [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), or using a custom format that you can build, as described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

[Here is a fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/zqdABB).